# How can I provide customised authentication for Appsync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

In appsync, there are 4 authorization mode, `API Key`, `IAM`, `Cognito`, `OPEN ID`. How can I make a customised one, like a lambda? Or how can I remove authorization at all which means it is open to public and I will do authorization in business layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppSync doesn't currently support custom Lambda authorizer, you can +1 the issue. https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/2

Regarding your second question, you can't remove authentication altogether, the closest you can get to it is use API_KEY (no authentication essentially as any client or person with your API_KEY can access your API.

Comment: `API_KEY` is only valid for 7 days. I am not sure how clients can extend the expiring date.

Comment: you can keep extending the expiration date of your API key indefinitely (as long as it's still valid) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateApiKey.html#API_UpdateApiKey_RequestBody

we do recognize 7 days is kind of short and we noted it will be convenient to allow for configuring the expiration for up to say a year in the future

Comment: clients don't extend the expiration date, one of your backend processes does (maybe a Lambda called by CW Events every 5 days). The idea here is you use a single API_KEY per application, and all your clients shared the same key. That way your API has virtually no authentication.